# Limit of decreasing sequences of markov time (stopping time) is markov time?

Tags: markov-process, stopping-times

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \{\mathcal{F}_t\}_{t \geqslant 0}, \mathbb{P})$ be a filtered probability space and let $\tau_n \geqslant \tau_{n+1}$ be a markov time (stopping time) with respect to filtering $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}_{t\geqslant 0}$. Also for every $\omega \in \Omega$ next limit is exist: $$lim_{n\to\infty} \tau_n = \tau_0$$
Will $\tau_0$ stopping time or not with respect to same filtering?

I proved following:
$\bigcap_{m \geqslant 1} \bigcup_{n \geqslant 1} \bigcap_{k \geqslant n} \{ \omega : \tau_k \leqslant t + \frac{1}{m} \} = \{ \tau_0 \leqslant t \}$

If left side of equal is measurable with respect to $ \mathcal{F}_t $ then $\tau_0$ - stopping time. A set from left side $ \{ \omega : \tau_k \leqslant t + \frac{1}{m} \} $ for every $ m \geqslant 1$  and every $ k \geqslant 1$ is measurable with respect to $ \mathcal{F}_{t+\frac{1}{m}} $. Therefore union of intersection (with index $k$) of these sets is measurable with respect to $ \mathcal{F}_{t+\frac{1}{m}} $ by definition of sigma-algebra.

And there is a first question: will the second intersection (with index $m$) of these sets, measurable with respect to $ \mathcal{F}_{t+\frac{1}{m}} $ ,be measurable with respect to $ \mathcal{F}_t $?

It seems non-measurable, so a second question following: Is there example of $\tau_n$ and $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}_{t \geqslant 0}$ in any book that can demonstrate it?

Comment: A counterexample worth keeping in mind is $X_t=\max\{t-T,0\}$ where $T$ is exponentially distributed, then the process $(X_t)_{t\geqslant0}$ is Markov (nifty, eh?) and it has some interesting properties. For example, each $\tau_n=\inf\{t>0\mid X_t=1/n\}$ is a stopping time, $\tau_n\geqslant\tau_{n+1}$, and $\tau_n\to\tau_0$ with $\tau_0=\inf\{t>0\mid X_t\ne0\}$ (which is simply $\tau_0=U$), which is **not** a stopping time for the canonical filtration of $(X_t)$.

Comment: @user1 IF other problem THEN post other question.